# which site to locate career question

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I asked a question to help myself and others identify which jobs in IT are more physically demanding.  From visiting programmers.stackexchange, security.stackexchange, serverfault, and stackoverflow, it seems that these sites can be good places to ask career-related questions, where the topics of career and information technology overlap.

I had a career question which might apply to all of these sites, but only one may be chosen (to not over-post), so I asked at [security.stackexchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/31215/what-are-the-more-physical-job-classes). It could be understandably closed for not being listed in the [faq](https://security.stackexchange.com/faq) or possibly too generalized. But I still think this a genuine question which *can* be answered constructively. Even if the answer is "it depends", it should be possible to list some classes of IT jobs which are most likely meet criteria X. (For example, we might already guess that a sysadmin job that has multiple sites is probably on your feet more than a web app developer job.). I'm just asking for people with anecdotal experience to help identify what jobs actually exist.

Could anyone please offer suggestions on how to better phrase this question or a better site to ask it? Thanks.

Comment: Generally career questions are not good on SE as they don't tend to have defined answers. Asking for lists of anecdotal experience is not a good fit. And it is not on topic here at all, as per the faq.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At this point I think your best bet would be to check out a site that's currently in beta, [The Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/).

It is all about asking general purpose questions about navigating the professional workplace with questions ranging from interview advice to this gem that ranked on the top of the super collider for a time, [How should I deal with an employee who has slept with my wife?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/7617/4850)